# PhpStorm 2017.1 - How Do I Get the Project Search Results to Appear As the Bottom Panel By Default?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I just upgraded to PhpStorm 2017.1 and noticed that when I do a directory search using the project explorer on the left hand side of the screen, the results now appear as a pop-up modal.

There is an option to get the results to appear as the bottom panel (like in previous versions) on the modal, but I would like it to do that by default.

How do I get the old behavior back?

Comment: *"the results now appear as a pop-up modal."* That's not 100% correct -- it's still just a preview -- just like it was before on separate "Preview" tab but now they are have placed all on one screen/tab. Now, back to the subject -- after you type your search query just click on the `Open in Find Window` button or hit `Ctrl+Enter` -- before you had to click on `Find` button with `Enter`, now a bit different shortcut.

Comment: @LazyOne Anyway to have the shortcut be just `Enter` like before instead of `Ctrl+Enter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have `Enter` work as `Ctrl+Enter`, please vote for [IDEA-169996](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169996).
Note that you can switch to the old dialog by deselecting `ide.find.as.popup` in Registry: Help | Find action, type *Registry* to locate it, find the option there and deselect the checkbox

Comment: I went on the link and couldn't find a vote button.  Democracy is way too complicated.  I prefer one man authoritarian regimes

Comment: You must be signed in to be able to vote... Please see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications